# How to get attribute value of span

Tags: jquery

On button click want the value from span

```
<td style="border-style:None;">
   <span data-needed="4080">
   <input id="MainContent_grdr1_chkCheck_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$grd2$ctl02$chkCheck"></span>
   <a id="MainContent_grdr1_lnkViewLog_0" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-graph" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$grdRatesAcknowledge$ctl02$lnkViewLog','')"><i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</td>
```

Tried with this code getting [object] as alert.

```
 <script>
     $('.btn-graph').on('click', function () {
     var proid = $(this).closest('span').find('data-needed');
     alert(proid);
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: `var proid = $(this).parent().find('span').attr('data-needed');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `attr()`

```
$('.btn-graph').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefult();
     var proid = $(this).prev('span').attr('data-needed');
     alert(proid);
     __doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$grdRatesAcknowledge$ctl02$lnkViewLog','')
}
```

Comment: Worked but have to remove e.preventDefult();

Comment: call `__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$grdRatesAcknowledge$ctl02$lnkViewLog','')` in this click event

Answer (score 1):

You can reach to closest `<td>` and then grab the associated `<span>` like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-graph').on('click', function() {
    var proid = $(this).closest('td').find("span").data("needed");
    alert(proid);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-style:None;">
      <span data-needed="4080">
   <input id="MainContent_grdr1_chkCheck_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$grd2$ctl02$chkCheck"></span>
      <a id="MainContent_grdr1_lnkViewLog_0" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-graph" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$grdRatesAcknowledge$ctl02$lnkViewLog','')"><i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>Click</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this:

```
$('.btn-graph').on('click', function () {
    var proid = $(this).parent().find('span').attr('data-needed');
    alert(proid);
});
```

Also you have the click function on `<a>` and it don't appear on HTML because you didn't have anything inside `<a>`

https://jsfiddle.net/zs67d8an/1/

Comment: there could be more td with this kind of mark up this wont work on that matter

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn-graph').on('click', function () {
        var proid = $(this).closest('td').find('span').attr("data-needed");           
        alert(proid);
});
```